# Pegar o valor de uma linha da tabela

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse script ele percorre a tabela e pega os valores.
Mas teria como restringe mais pegando somente a linha que acionou o evento.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change','table tbody tr td input',function(){
            
            var v = 0;
            
            $('input').each(function(i,e) {   
            
   if(i > 8)
   {
    return true;
   }
   
            if(i !== 2)
            {
                if ($(e).val())
    {
                  var i = $(e).val().replace(/\,/g,'.');
                  
                  if (isNaN(i)) { $(e).val(''); return; }
                      
                  v += parseFloat(i);
               
                  $('.total').val( v.toFixed(2));
            
                }
            }
            
            });
            
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<th>
VALOR 1
</th>
<th>
VALOR 2
</th>
<th>
TOTAL
</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control total' disabled/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control total' disabled/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Podes usar `$(this).closest('tr').find('input'). each etc `em vêz de `$('input'). each`. É isso que procuras?

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo a sua pergunta, tem como pegar na linha sim, basta ao invés de fazer a busca por todos inputs, procurar por um ancestral comum, no caso a `tr`, e depois fazer a busca pelos inputs a partir deste ancestral. Segue seu código alterado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change','table tbody tr td input',function(){
            
            var v = 0;
            
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input').each(function(i,e) {   
            
   if(i > 8)
   {
    return true;
   }
   
            if(i !== 2)
            {
                if ($(e).val())
    {
                  var i = $(e).val().replace(/\,/g,'.');
                  
                  if (isNaN(i)) { $(e).val(''); return; }
                      
                  v += parseFloat(i);
               
                  $(this).closest('tr').find('.total').val( v.toFixed(2));
            
                }
            }
            
            });
            
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<th>
VALOR 1
</th>
<th>
VALOR 2
</th>
<th>
TOTAL
</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control total' disabled/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control'/>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='name0' placeholder='' class='form-control total' disabled/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Detalhando a alteração `$(this).closest('tr').find('input')...`:

- `$(this)`: Retorna o elemento que acionou o evento `onchange`, no caso, um input.
- `closest('tr')`: Procura o ancestral mais próximo que satisfaça o seletor, no caso apenas procurando pela tag `tr`.
- `find('input')`: Procura pelo seletor por todos ancestrais dos objetos retornados na função anterior.